# Calling a generic function in VB.NET / C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, generics

Question: I want to call a generic function, defined as:

```
      Public Shared Function DeserializeFromXML(Of T)(Optional ByRef strFileNameAndPath As String = Nothing) As T
```

Now when I call it, I wanted to do it with any of the variants below:

```
Dim x As New XMLserialization.cConfiguration
x = XMLserialization.XMLserializeLDAPconfig.DeserializeFromXML(Of x)()
x = XMLserialization.XMLserializeLDAPconfig.DeserializeFromXML(GetType(x))()
x = XMLserialization.XMLserializeLDAPconfig.DeserializeFromXML(Of GetType(x))()
```

But it doesn't work.
I find it very annoying and unreadable having to type

```
    x = XMLserialization.XMLserializeLDAPconfig.DeserializeFromXML(Of XMLserialization.cConfiguration)()
```

Is there a way to call a generic function by getting the type from the instance ?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds to me like you want to create a shorter alias for your `XMLserialization.cConfiguration` type. Try using the `Imports` statement to accomplish this:

```vb
' at the top of the file
Imports C = XMLserialization.cConfiguration

' somewhere in the body of the file
Dim x = XMLserialization.XMLserializeLDAPconfig.DeserializeFromXML(Of C)()
```

Answer (score 3):

Generics and reflection make very poor friends. However, you *can* do this via [MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5...). However, that is going to be hard and ugly.

Since `XmlSerializer` is based around `Type` instance - I would reverse things: have the *realy* code `Type` based, and call into that from the shallow generic version; example in C#:

```
public T DeserializeFromXML<T>(string path) {
   return (T)DeserializeFromXML(typeof(T), path);
}
public object DeserializeFromXML(Type type, string path) {
    //TODO: real code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only using the methods of the `System.Reflection` namespace, which really isn't worth it for the effort you're trying to save.

Answer (score 1):

The type of a generic method is determined at compile time, which is why you can't set it using a variable. This is a key difference between generic programming and type reflection.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason why you can't do this easily in code and why the reflection is so much extra work: generics are all about preserving type, so you can have a `List(Of Integer)` instead of a `List(Of Object)` and have to cast/box everything, and they improve code-maintainability by maintaining strong typing through the code (so you get fewer run-time cast and type exceptions).

Generics are really compile-time. They let you defer the type being specified so that your generic code can be re-used or have the type specified by another assembly.

However your deserialisation is run time - you don't know what type you'll have when you're writing the code, which is why you need a variable to hold the type. In this case there isn't really any benefit to having the generic code - your serialisation costs will be orders of magnitude greater than the boxing cost, and there's no code-maintainability benefit for the strongly typed result as you still don't know what it is at compile-time.

In short, this being hard is .Net's way of telling you to review your initial assumptions - change your method to:

```
Public Shared Function DeserializeFromXML(Optional ByRef strFileNameAndPath As String = Nothing) As Object
```

And then cast your result from object to your `XMLserialization.cConfiguration` class.

Answer (score 0):

*[This is answering the question as asked, not necessarily solving your bigger issue.]*

To avoid the `Of cConfiguration` being required you could include an ignored `ByVal Configuration As T` in the generic method.

Then you could say

```
x = DeserializeFromXML(x)
```

But @DanTao's answer is probably better than mine unless you find a use for the `Configuration` parameter.